# Is the matrix corresponding to an equivalence relation positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $|X| < \infty$ and $(X,R)$ be an equivalence relation. Define the $|X| \times |X|$ matrix $A$ by

$$(A)_{ij} = \begin{cases}1 & (i,j) \in R,\\0 & \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Is this matrix positive semidefinite? Is there a simple way to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is positive semidefinite. To see it, note that $A$ is similar to a block matrix of the form 
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 1_{k_1} \\ 
                 &  1_{k_2}\\
                  &  & \ddots \\ 
                   & & & & 1_{k_l}
\end{pmatrix}
$$where $1_n \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$ denotes an $n \times n$-matrix having only $1$s as entries (just arange the elements of $X$ according to thier $R$-class). As $1_n$ is positive semidefinite (being symmetric and having eigenvalues $n$, and $0$ ($n-1$ times)), $A$ is also.

Comment: We have $$ 1_{k_1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ \vdots & & & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ ($k_1$ rows and columns),

Comment: Sorry, I misread. That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A$ is equal to $I$ plus the adjacency matrix of a graph consisting of a disjoint union of cliques. The eigenvalues of a clique $K_n$ are well-known to be $n-1$ and $-1$ and the spectrum of a disjoint union of graphs is the union of the spectra of the connected components. It follows that $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: My question actually arose from this. I had a graph and the matrix $A$ had entries $1$ if two vertices belonged to the same connected component and $0$ otherwise. However, I did not know about the eigenvalues of a clique (or maybe I just forgot).